# c++11 regex lookahead exclude word

Tags: regex, c++11

I have a string list:

1. ReferencePrice
2. ReferenceCurrentPrice
3. CostPrice
4. AverageCostPrice
   ...

I want to filter out all strings that:

1. Containing 'Price',
2. But not containing 'CostPrice'

My regex is '**(?!Cost)Price**', but it can match the 3rd string 'CostPrice', why? and what is the correct regex?

---

After some investigation, I know what 'lookahead' means. It means **look right**, so similarly lookbehind means **look left**.

The correct regex should be a negative lookbehind regex:

```
(?<!Cost)Price
```

Try it: https://regex101.com/r/m3238r/1

Unfortunately, c++11 doesn't support lookbehind. Boost regex does.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html

Comment: You need a "look behind" instead, which C++11 apparently doesn't support.

Comment: @ClasG is it possible to use c++11 regex for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having to take of soon, I'll answer with an (in my opinion) silly solution (there must be much better ones :P).

```
((?!Cost)....|^.{0,3})Price
```

If preceded by 4 characters (atleast), make sure it isn't `Cost`. Alternatively, make sure there aren't more than 3 characters preceding `Price`.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/45fulb/1).

Comment: Good explanation and doc. Thanks. Don't know if there are better ones.

Comment: Could be simplified as ((?!Cost).{4}|^.{0,3})Price :-)

Comment: @user1633272 True. That makes it perform better, but imo, when the length of the regex isn't shortened, `....` is easier to read/understand.